# can not mark material in asset, option not showed

Tags: asset

[image]
there is not option to maerk the material in my asset. some know why?

Comment: Do you have an asset library set up and paths set under Preferences > File Paths > Asset Libraries?

Comment: yes i have it. there is no problem to mark modells as asset, but by material does not show the button, very strange

Comment: Very strange as you say. I've not seen that before. Does it just happen in that window or is it the same if you try to add it from the Shading viewport window too?

Comment: Hello. Try disabling all third party addons. also check any error messages in the console with Window > toggle system console. And of course make sure your blender version is > 3.0

Comment: only in that windows, in another PC works with asset function.